# How to encrypt data so as to perform SQL queries with LIKE?

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, encryption, encryption-symmetric

Please be patient, I'm not an expert about cryptography. My question is probably very basic but I googled a lot and I'm still confused.

In a PHP project, I need to encrypt/decrypt the data saved in the database. In a previous project I used the aes128 encryption and everything went well. But now I have a different need. I need to perform queries in the database using the operator LIKE. And obviously the encryption of a portion of a string is not included in the encryption of the whole string.

Googling around, I realized that maybe I have to use symmetric-key algorithm (like the Caesar's cipher). But I did a test with the php-encryption library (https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) and I got the following result:

> MAMMA = ÿŸNq!!83=S™÷á;Bª¯‚óØ š‹ æ%§0  %? _† Ÿ&0c—âÐÜÉ/:LSçï; Õµå¬£§.öÒ9
>
> MAMMAMIA = (Ò Î{yG :   [&¶›J'Õ6÷ííG£V­­{ÉsÙ=qÝ×.:ÍÔ j…Qž¹×j¶óóþ¡ÔnÛŠ *å­n\hhN

The encryption of the first word is not included in the encryption of the second. Evidently the simmetric algorithm is not right for my need.

What I can use to reach my goal using PHP? Thanks!

Comment: Caesar cipher (or any other per-letter cipher) should work just fine.

Comment: Using some old fashioned algorithms like ceasar cipher is not really recommended. It's simply not secure at all.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that these algorithms are not secure. Is there a way to achieve my goal in security (and with PHP)?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use mysql encrypt/decrypt functionality and do both "on the fly".

To insert and encrypt data:

```
insert into mytable (secret) values AES_ENCRYPT('SomeTextToHide','myPassword');
```

To search for encrypted values using `like`

```
select * from mytable where AES_DECRYPT(secret,'myPassword') like '%text%';
```

Comment: Ok but, for a few reasons, I have to encrypt via php

Comment: If you use only php for encryption then you logically can not query the database tables using like if you apply any secure algorithm for encryption. Think about it...

Comment: You're right but I can't change it and this is why I thought about a substitution cypher...

Comment: A substitution cipher can be secure (depends on use case) like e.g. AES in ECB mode.  But you need a substitution cipher where one phrase is encoded to the same string under any circumstances. This type of algorithm (like ceasar cipher) is a complete catastrophe when it comes to security.

Comment: Googling around I have found that the approach suggested in the answer "is flawed from a security perspective, since your data AND the encryption key are likely flowing through either a socket to the DB server. This also allows people to just log the queries and catch any calls to AES_* functions". Is this correct?

Comment: As the decryption has to take place some where the encryption key will always be "flying around". If your (database) server gets compromised your in big trouble - that's true.

Comment: @maxhb - database data gets leaked all the time: http://www.networkworld.com/article/3011103/security/biggest-data-breaches-of-2015.html

Comment: Without SSL to the database it is very weak, with SSL it requires a DB user become malevolent.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of being able to use a LIKE clause and its wildcards on securely encrypted data is a set of two mutually exclusive desires.

You can securely encrypt your data, OR you can use a LIKE clause with wildcards.  You cannot do both at once, because the LIKE clause itself would bypass the encryption!

```
SELECT * WHERE data LIKE 'a%'
SELECT * WHERE data LIKE 'b%'
...
SELECT * WHERE data LIKE '_a%'
SELECT * WHERE data LIKE '_b%'
...
SELECT * WHERE data LIKE '__a%'
SELECT * WHERE data LIKE '__b%'
...
```

If you securely encrypt the data in the database, then you need to pull ALL of it back local, decrypt it all, and then do your wildcard searches on the decrypted data.